Klarna Payment Gatway In Laravel
I'm using Laravel 10 and I want to use Klarna Payment Gateway using composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
Following is my code to get payment I not want to use tax therefor I use 0 but it give me error
public function createKlarnaOrder(Request $request)
    {
        $orderData = [
            'purchase_country' => 'GB',
            'purchase_currency' => 'GBP',
            'locale' => 'en-GB',
            'order_amount' => $request->amount,
            'order_lines' => [
                [
                    'type' => 'physical',
                    'reference' => '123050',
                    'name' => 'Product Name',
                    'quantity' => 1,
                    'unit_price' => $request->amount, // Ensure this matches the total amount for single quantity
                    'tax_rate' => 0, // Set to 0 if no tax
                    'total_amount' => $request->amount,
                    'total_tax_amount' => 0, // Set to 0 if no tax
                ]
            ]
        ];
        // Log::info('Klarna Order Data: ', $orderData);

        $orderResponse = $this->klarnaService->createOrder($orderData);

        if (isset($orderResponse['html_snippet'])) {
            return response()->json([
                'redirectUrl' => $orderResponse['redirect_url']
            ]);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Failed to create Klarna order'
        ], 500);
    }

following is error I'm getting
local.ERROR: Klarna order creation failed: Client error: `POST https://api.playground.klarna.com/checkout/v3/orders` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"error_code":"BAD_VALUE","error_messages":["Bad value: order_tax_amount"],"correlation_id":"367cf629-a926-4bc8-bdf9-b82 (truncated...)
  


So far, you specified the tax amount for your one order item only. But you still need to specify the tax amount of the complete order. https://github.com/tuutti/php-klarna-payments/blob/3.x/docs/Model/CreateOrderRequest.md

order_tax_amount int Total tax amount of the order. The value should be in non-negative minor units. Eg: 25 Euros should be 2500. [optional]
